# How to create a method dispatch delegate in c# that takes the target as first argument

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

The basic way to create a delegate to access a private property setter in c# is

```
public static Action<T> GetPrivatePropertySetter<T>(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    var t = obj.GetType();
    var td = typeof(Action<T>);
    var method = t.GetMethod("set_" + propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var dlg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(td, obj, method);
    return (Action<T>)dlg;
}
```

is there any way to create a delegate like below

```
public static Action<O,T> GetPrivatePropertySetter<O,T>(string propertyName)
{

}
```

where I might do

```
var nameSetter = GetPrivatePropertySetter<MyClass>("Name");
var myObject = new MyClass(name: "Foo");
nameSetter(myObject, "Bar");
```

I would like to cache these delegates and have only one per method per class instead of one per method per instance. Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: is there anything speaking against a singleton object that holds a Dictionary<Type,Dictionary<String,SomeClassToHoldTheSetterAndMetaData>> ?

Comment: What does this have to do with the question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Expression trees to generate needed delegate in runtime. It will be usual Action, that will be compiled from expression to usual method. The cool thing about it that it require some small time to compile it, but then there is no difference between using this Action, or assigned this property directly. So performance won't be affected.

Here is a generator code:

```
public static Action<TObj, TProp> GenerateSetter<TObj, TProp>(string propertyName)
{
    var type = typeof(TObj);
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    MethodInfo setterMethodInfo = property.SetMethod;

    ParameterExpression paramo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObj), "param");
    ParameterExpression parami = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProp), "newvalue");

    MethodCallExpression methodCallSetterOfProperty = Expression.Call(paramo, setterMethodInfo, parami);
    Expression setPropertyValueExp = Expression.Lambda(methodCallSetterOfProperty, paramo, parami);

    var setPropertyValueLambda = (Expression<Action<TObj, TProp>>)setPropertyValueExp;
    var setterFunc = setPropertyValueLambda.Compile();
    return setterFunc;
}
```

And here is sample of usage:

```
Action<A, string> action = GenerateSetter<A, string>("Test");
A obj = new A();
action(obj, "newValue");
```

And here is My A object that I've used:

```
public class A
{
    private string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Works really well. I've used the code in the following scenario and cached the delegates using a threadlocal cache. https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/8421878

Comment: Though I had to add another binding flag to get it working for me. ``BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic``

Answer (score 1):

Is there a public getter?  I'd prefer a more strongly typed approach using expressions (if I had to - you should probably prefer *not* to break encapsulation like this!)

e.g.

```
public Action<T, TProperty> CreateSetter<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
{
    ParameterExpression newValue = Expression.Parameter(property.Body.Type);

    Expression<Action<T, TProperty>> assign = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, TProperty>>(
        Expression.Assign(property.Body, newValue),
        property.Parameters[0], newValue);

    Action<T, TProperty> action = assign.Compile();

    return action;
}
```

usage:

```
var nameSetter = CreateSetter<MyClass, string>(c => c.Name);
nameSetter(obj, "newValue");
```

Comment: At a higher level in the code I use what you are doing. At the lower level I'm working with the string name which was generated by the typesafe method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be [Open Instance Delegates](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2010/07/27/introduction-to-open-instance-delegates/)

Comment: I have better approach, wait a sec